# Mobile cross-browser web testing

Tags: testing, web-applications, cross-browser

When building websites I commonly use tools such as [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org) to ensure that my pages looks reasonably OK in the different browsers. I am however starting to get complaints about a heap of mobile browsers running on different portable devices.

My question is simply how do one best carry out mobile cross-browser tests ? (answers that  does not require me to install a ton of different mobile emulators will be preferred).

Comment: Though not exactly what you want, I think http://quirksmode.org/mobile/ may be helpful.

Comment: `answers that does not require me to install a ton of different mobile emulators`: I have bad news ...

Comment: How about sticking to the standards and the good practices (like the alt-poperty of the img-tag), while checking the major browsers, and blaiming the mobile browsers when they don't render stuff right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DeviceAnywhere](http://deviceanywhere.com/) can do this, but not for free.

Comment: It does indeed provide access to a heap of mobile phones, and from there one can use their browser. But I would prefer some service where I can just post a URL and get immediate pictures back of how it looks in various mobile browsers.

Comment: @Lars: “pictures […] of how it looks in various mobile browsers” are not very useful; especially the way a mobile browser app ‘feels’ (e.g. touchscreen, scrolling, zooming) differs from desktop browsers and from mobile browsers mutually.

Comment: You do have a point with the pictures, but the DeviceAnywhere solution still seams overly complicated in comparison with services like browsershots.org. So I am still pursuing a solution where I can just post a url and get at least some (imperfect) idea on how my site looks on the most common mobile devices.

Comment: DeviceAnywhere definitely does more than you need it to, but it should be possible to write an automation script that works like browsershots.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are old.
Nowadays, there are many more options.
Check out "Browserstacks", or google for "alternatives to Browserstacks". Some services offer (paid) automation for testing across devices.

Answer (score 0):

http://validator.w3.org/mobile/ will provide you with several good advices, but won't provide any mobile devices' screenshots...

I'm afraid Felipe's right, the only way to know how your website interacts is to do it yourself.