# Cross mobile browser testing

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, cross-browser, virtualization

> What is the best way to test my website across various mobile browsers AND various versions of each of those browsers.

---

***Additional Info:***

Most of the online cross browser testing support wide range of desktop browser testing, and quite a range of mobile devices. But they don't seem to offer various versions of mobile browsers on those devices.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147488/mobile-cross-browser-web-testing) similar question is quite old and it is surprising that in spite of the proliferation of mobile devices and focus on responsive designs, testing services for mobile is not catching up.

Major mobile browsers I would like to target : various mobile versions of Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Dolphin, UC Web etc

---

Just wanted to note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541225/cross-browser-testing-all-major-browsers-on-one-machine) and [this](http://utilu.com/UtiluMFC/) good alternative to online testing services for desktop browsers. Maybe something similar exists for mobile browsers too?

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest that both Opera's "device mode" is a really good for a first crack. But nothing beats actual device testing. I have found the odd case where Chrome's iPhone mode renders something different than what the actual phone does, but I would say it is about 90%. And the fact that it is so much easier to tweak code, and refresh using Chrome on the desktop rather than tweak, and refresh on phone, that I tolerate the 10% difference as long as I can. Then I just verify on an actual device after I am done with Chome's device mode.

I have not used Opera's device mode, but have heard it is good too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called as https://www.browserling.com/ which can be used for Desktop and Mobile testing(Android)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is one way of doing cross browser testing across various mobile browsers and versions. It all boils down to what you want to do?

It is impossible to cover ALL browser combinations and versions. So my suggestion based on experience would be-

- If you have too many combinations in mind, use a combinatorial tool (pairwise testing) from here - http://www.pairwise.org/tools.asp and reduce the number of permutations to get the best coverage.
- Then go to Android and Apple website to see what the most commonly used phones and versions in the US, Europe and Asia region are based on where your customers are located. They have all these stats publicly available on their website
- If you have google analytics see what browsers, versions and phones your users most commonly use to access your website

Now, you will have a list of devices and browser versions which is more focused.

- Check what budget you have to invest in cross browser testing. Based on that I would recommend buying at least a couple of phones and tablets based on the usage statistics you got in the first 3 steps. Then, you can choose from a number of cross browser testing tools/services like

  - [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/)
  - [Amazon Devices Farm](https://www.browserstack.com/)
  - [Saucelabs](https://www.browserstack.com/)

Now atleast you have a more scientific way of doing cross browser testing :-)